# Point Combo multipliers in score system

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i'm kind new to programming and currently developing an endless run game on Unity with c#.
I'm stuck at making my score system work properly.

The player collects score points based on distance traveled. So in the script that manages Score in `Update()` I have:

```
distance += Vector2.Distance(Player.transform.position, lastPosition);
lastPosition = Player.transform.position;

baseScore = distance;
```

And that's working fine.

In this game you get rewarded for not hitting obstacles for a certain amount of distance traveled, so in the player controller script I wrote:

```
public void Update()
{
    distanceTraveled += Vector2.Distance(transform.position, lastPosition);
    lastPosition = transform.position;

    if (distanceTraveled >= 10)
    {
        NoHitCombo = NoHitCombo + 2;
        distanceTraveled = 0;
    }
    [...] 
 }
```

and

```
public void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
if (other.gameObject.tag == "Obstacle")
{
    NoHitCombo = 0;
    distanceTraveled = 0;
}
```

So if i'm not hitting anything my score gain while NoHitCombo > 0 should be *2, *4, *6 etc.

for example:

At the start and i'm gaining distance as score. 
While NoHitCombo is 2 I want to calculate a new value, which is `"Distance since NoHitCombo value has changed * NoHitCombo"`. If its 4 i want another value to calculate distance * 4 and so on.

i tried writing smt like that in `Update()`:

```
Finalscore = baseScore * NoHitCombo;
```

but that's not working as my score is changing alongside with NoHitCombo value.
i tried stuff with `if (nohitcombo > 0)` but nothing worked as intended.

I think I miss something to complete the puzzle, everything i tried is wrong. 
I rly can't figure out to solve this. I do probably need to store the value of the distance traveled while a multiplier is active and as soon as it changes it should add that value to the score

Any help would be rly appreciated
ps English isn't my mother language, sorry about that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about re-using the "distance since last frame" value you already get like

```
private void Update()
{
    var distanceSinceLastFrame = Vector2.Distance(transform.position, lastPosition);
    lastPosition = transform.position;

    // ...

    distanceTraveled += distanceSinceLastFrame;
    if (distanceTraveled >= 10)
    {
        NoHitCombo = NoHitCombo + 2;
        distanceTraveled = 0;
    }

    // ...

                                           // if NoHitCombo is 0 use 1 instead
    FinalScore += distanceSinceLastFrame * NoHitCombo == 0 ? 1 : NoHitCombo;
}
```

so instead of always setting the `FinalScore` to a fix calculated value instead you add the `distanceSinceLastFrame * NoHitCombo` to the current value.

Comment: It is actually working as intended now!! Just not working when NoHitCombo = 0. Anyway thank you so much, i was stuck here since yesterday :DD